# Stacks for application windows in OS X

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, stacks

Can stacks be created for application windows in mac os x - leopard? For example, if I click on firefox, it should show a stack of all open firefox windows and I could choose between them.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can switch to the application and use Exposé to see all the windows. In 10.6 (Snow Leopard) you can click-and-hold on an icon in the Dock to bring up Exposé for the application, but not in 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

[HyperDock](http://hyperdock.bahoom.com) aims to copy Windows 7's *Aero Peek* feature, which could be described as "Stacks for application windows".

Screenshot from product web site:

[image]